# Firebase iOS isn't getIDTokenForcingRefresh strictly better than getIDToken

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

By passing `false` to `Auth.auth().currentUser?.getIDTokenForcingRefresh`, the function does the same thing as `getIDToken`, except that in case when the current token is expired it will refresh the token. So isn't using `getIDTokenForcingRefresh` strictly better than using `getIDToken`? In what situation would anybody use `getIDToken` instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. It's better to use

```
func getIDTokenForcingRefresh(_ forceRefresh: Bool, completion: AuthTokenCallback? = nil)
```

But you should be careful about the `forceRefresh` param. If you set `forceRefresh` to `true` then it will refresh the token every time you call the method.

Rather you can also use

```
func getIDToken(completion: AuthTokenCallback? = nil)
```

Calling this method will refresh your token if needed, you don't have to take care about the `forceRefresh` param.

Comment: I thought getIDToken doesn't refresh even if it's expired? It's not in the documentation. So are you saying getIDToken has the same effect as passing false to getIDTokenForcingRefresh?

Comment: `Retrieves the Firebase authentication token, possibly refreshing it if it has expired.` You can check that in this documentation [-getIDTokenWithCompletion:]https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/FIRUser#/c:objc(cs)FIRUser(im)getIDTokenWithCompletion:

Comment: I see. So this and getIDTokenForcingRefresh with a false argument are indeed equivalent...

Comment: If my answer helps you, please accept and up vote :) thanks

Comment: What happens if you make 2 or more concurrent requests with expired Token? Will it refresh it multiple times?